# How to share a music folder between OSX and Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, itunes, music

It's a question for OSX & Windows 7 users who jump between one system to another.

I'm on Windows now, and I've got this music folder in my main hard drive. I'm planning to buy a Mackbook Pro soon and I need to share this folder (along with Pictures and Documents but that's something easy to do), and maybe an external HD or a network solution.

On OSX i would use iTunes, and its library system is problematic for sharing.

On Windows i use MusicBee, a simple music app that constantly watches a folder for changes.

What do?

Answer (score 0):

You can install iTunes in Windows also and follow this [method](http://lifehacker.com/230605/hack-attack-share-your-itunes-music-library-over-your-home-network).

Comment: but I hate iTunes for Windows.